# Create new vector for each element in an existing vector?

Tags: r

I have an existing vector (type: character), for instance

```
A = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday")
```

Now I would like to create a new empty vector for all elements in the existing vector. Not manually like

```
(Monday=c(), Tueday=c(),...)
```

I tried a for loop

```
for (i in A) {
 print(i) =c()
 }
```

but that didn't work, hope you have suggestions.

Comment: This is not how R works. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in A) {
  assign(i, c())
}

# Now list all objects in workspace
ls()
[1] "A"         "Friday"    "i"         "Monday"   
[5] "Thursday"  "Tuesday"   "Wednesday"
```

But this is how I would assign an empty vector instead of `c()`:

```
vector(mode = "character", length = n) 
# where n = 0 in your case
```